# Inequality involving ceiling of square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $r$ is such that $r^2$ is an integer, is this expression true for all real $R$? ($r$ and $R$ are always positive)
$$
r < R \iff r^2 < \lceil R^2 \rceil
$$

It is for programming a script in which pixels around a central pixel are classified by their squared radius $r^2$ (always whole), and only those where the radius $r$ is less than a given value $R$ (can be fractional) should be selected.

Is there an easy way to prove this equivalence (going from right to left) algebraically?

Comment: Because $r^2$ is an integer, we have $\lceil R^2\rceil >r^2\implies R^2>r^2$. So yes.

Comment: Irrelevant if $r^2$ is an integer.  As $\lceil K \rceil \ge K$ always,  And $0 < r < R\implies r^2 < R^2$,  we will *always* have $0 < r < R \implies r^2 < R^2 \le \lceil R^2 \rceil$.

Comment: @fleablood: I am having trouble parsing your first sentence. Do you mean "Irrelevant _whether_ $r^2$ is an integer"? Or "If $r^2$ is an integer, then <something-or-other> is irrelevant"? In any case, my comment addresses the backward implication, not the forward, and for this it is certainly not irrelevant whether $r^2$ is an integer.

Comment: I meant it was irrelevant *whether* $r^2$ was an integer.  But I mistakenly was assuming forward implication:  (Giver $r,R$ are positive) then $r < R \implies r^2 < R^2 \le [R^2]$.  Backward implication is clearly not generally true: Given $r,R$ positive we can have $r^2<\lceil R^2\rceil$ but $R\le r$ if $\lfloor R^2\rfloor <R^2\le r^2<\lceil R^2\rceil$.  But as you point out in your comment, if we have a restriction that $r^2\in \mathbb Z$ such is impossible: $r^2<\lceil R^2\rceil\implies r^2\le \lceil R^2\rceil-1<R^2\implies r< R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma:  If $i,j \in \mathbb Z$ and $i < j$ then $i\le j-1$.

Pf by contradiction:  Assume not.  Assume $i> j-1$.  But we know $i < j$ so we have $j-1 < i < j$.  But $j\in \mathbb Z$.  Those there are no integers between $j-1$ and $j$.  ($j$ is the successor of $j-1$ and there are no integers between an integer and it's successor.)  So $i$ is not an integer thus we have a contradiction.

Thus:

If $r \ge 0$ and $R \ge 0$ and $r^2 \in \mathbb Z$ and $r^2 <  \lceil R^2 \rceil$ then $r < R$.

Pf:

By definition $ \lceil R^2 \rceil\in \mathbb Z$ and $ \lceil R^2 \rceil- 1 < R^2 \le  \lceil R^2 \rceil$.

Thus if $r^2 \in \mathbb Z$ and $r^2 <  \lceil R^2 \rceil$ then by the lemma we have

$r^2 \le  \lceil R^2 \rceil-1$.  And thus $0 \le r^2 \le  \lceil R^2 \rceil-1 <  R^2$ or $0 < r^2 < R^2$.

As $0\ge r$ and $R\ge 0$ we have $r \le R \iff r^2 < R^2$ so we have $r < R$.

....

Lemma (if you need it):  If $r, R$ are both positive then $r < R \iff r^2 < R^2$.

Pf:  If $0 \le r < R$ then $r^2 = r\cdot r < r\cdot R < R\cdot R = R^2$.

Contrapositively, if $R \le r$ (but $r, R$ are positive) then $R^2 = R\cdot R \le r\cdot R \le r\cdot r = r^2$ so $R^2 \le r^2$ and $r^2 < R^2$ is impossible.  So $r^2 < R^2 \implies r < R$.

Answer (score 0):

We begin with $0<r<R$, and we know $R^2 \le \lceil R^2 \rceil$.

First, multiply the first equation through by $r$ to obtain: $0<r^2<rR$. Next, multiply the first equation through by $R$ to obtain: $0<rR<R^2$.

Combine results: $r^2<rR<R^2\le \lceil R^2 \rceil$.

Comment: Actually (though I misread as well) the OP is asking about the other direction.  Does $r^2<  \lceil R^2 \rceil \implies r < R$.  Which.... in general, no, but if $r^2 \in \mathbb Z$, yes.